# An Edit That I Don't Agree With

Tags: discussion, aggressive-edits

Earlier today I answered [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61814/someone-keeps-moving-the-stuff-on-my-desk/61816#61816) question.

An [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/61816/revisions) removed my final paragraph, with the comment that I'm giving advice on how to get away with an illegal activity.

Personally I don't think my advice is out of line, and I also feel that the edit is removing an important piece of my answer. Perhaps not the "meat" of it, but still something that I wrote and stand by.

I feel that if the community takes issue with my opinion the answer should be down-voted, or commented on, not edited by someone who does not agree and has the reputation to impose his opinion on my post.

Am I in the wrong to think that this edit was out of line?

Comment: If you feel it was out of line, roll it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If somebody edits your work in a way that changes its meaning or removes content you feel is important to your answer, then you as the author get the final say.<sup>1</sup>  If you think the edit was well-intentioned but missed the mark, and if the editor left clues (comment or revision summary), see if you can address whatever it was that made that person edit in the first place.  But if it's a case where you just disagree (looks like that's the case here), you're free to roll back.  Objections to an answer can be lodged through votes, constructive comments, meta discussions, or in extreme cases deletion.

That's for *answers*.  *Questions* affect more people, so the community is generally allowed to exert more pressure there, e.g. to edit out rants that overwhelm the actual question.  I can't really be more precise there (I think we all play that somewhat by ear); I'm just pointing out that the cases are a little different.

<sup>1</sup> The one exception to this, which doesn't apply here, is if somebody edited out content that a reasonable person would find offensive, abusive, or otherwise inappropriate -- content that would otherwise lead to the post's deletion. Since editing is a smaller change than deletion, people might try that if the rest of the post seems worth keeping.